# People Search result scoping

Tags: 2010, enterprise-search, search-scope, people-search

I have a server farm for three organisations (unfortunately they are all sharing the same user profile service app).  There are three web apps with site collections (one web app with a site coll per org).

When we do a people search results from other organisations are displayed on the people search.  Unfortunately we cannot use the organisation to filter the search results as everyone is a member of the same org in AD.

Is there a way to filter search results by the email address (i.e. from @ onwards)? if so how?

If not, is there an alternative way to achieve a people search that only returns people within a specific org based on their email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Navigate to the people search results
- Click on site actions
- Click on edit page
- Edit the People Search Core results web part
- Expand the Results Query options section
- Enter the text **WorkEmail:”*org1.com”** in Append Text to query
- Click ok
- Save & close the page
- Publish the page

Comment: SharePoint doesn't support prefix wildcards, this won't work.

Comment: it seems to be working - has it been changed in later service packs for 2010? I guess i could try just changing it to **WorkEmail:"org1.com"** to see if I get the same results.

Comment: Interesting, the second query WorkEmail:"org1.com" is a contains query and may work. I still prefer using company as it is unambiguous.

Comment: Yeah - like I said I would normally prefer that too but unfortunately AD is unlikely to get tidied up enough to be able to rely on that.

Comment: Remember, you can edit the properties in the User Profile Service too. For example you could use PowerShell to tidy up.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the Company AD property to the import from AD into the User Profiles and then create a scope based on that attribute. Any attribute will work for creating the scope but I have found Company works well in scenarios like yours.

Comment: This is normally what I would do, but AD is a mess and needs tidied up, so for now the prefix text seems to be working.